# Чи слово "неповнорідний" є літературним?

Tags: вживання-слів, прикметники

У романі Сергія Бута “Листи з того світу” прочитала таке речення:

> Залізна витримка, продемонстрована **неповнорідним** братом Ельзи Олександрівни, збила з пантелику.

Зацікавило слово **неповнорідний**. Звернулася у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/nepovnoridnyj), а там такого немає. Однак у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82) все ж така стаття є:

> ***Неповнорідний*** — такий, що має лише спільного батька або лише спільну матір.

Отож, слово **неповнорідний** все ж є літературним чи ні?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [Словнику гендерних термінів](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=J8tBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85&source=bl&ots=Sz-mUqRTFk&sig=fgBm2TiGSGi2aiQTnRlFVdoAQZs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWyIOu_MHaAhUHJpoKHSuACF0Q6AEITjAE#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false) знаходимо:

> Брати і сестри можуть бути **повнорідні** й **неповнорідні**. **Повнорідними** визнавали братів і сестер, які мали спільних батька і матір. Якщо брати і сестри мали спільного батька, але різних матерів, вони були **неповнорідними**, але єдинокровними; якщо мали спільну матір, але різних батьків — вони неповнорідні, але єдиноутробні.

У [Сімейному кодексі](http://zakon5.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2947-14/ed20030101) також знаходимо :

> *Стаття 26. Особи, які не можуть перебувати у шлюбі між собою* 
>   2. У  шлюбі між собою не можуть перебувати рідні (**повнорідні, 
>   неповнорідні**) брат і сестра.  **Повнорідними** є брати і  сестри,  які 
>   мають спільних батьків. **Неповнорідними** є брати і сестри, які мають 
>   спільну матір або спільного батька.

Наявність слова **неповнорідний** знаходимо також у [Про внесення змін до статті 23 Закону України "Про мобілізаційну підготовку та мобілізацію"[...]](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/en/1387-19) :

> "жінки та чоловіки, чиї близькі родичі (чоловік, дружина, син, донька, батько, мати, дід, баба або рідний (**повнорідний, неповнорідний**) брат чи сестра) загинули або пропали безвісти під час проведення антитерористичної операції з числа.

Отже, слово **неповнорідний** є нормативним.